# Get Scroll textview focus by disabling parent Scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, textview

I have a scrollview wrappng a number of subviews including text view.

When running the app I am Having problems getting scrolling focus on the parent scrollview and on the textView, that is it confusing for the user when trying to scroll the textview as sometimes the entire view will scroll instead.

So I want to disable the scrollview when the textview is fully visible, so only the textview will scroll when user interacts with screen.

```
// Set scrollview size in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(self.view.frame.width, 1050);
```

Any input appreciated.

Comment: You're not asking a UI/UX question, but you should be.  And I'd absolutely recommend against nesting scrollviews.  It makes for a horrible user experience, as you've discovered.

Comment: So is there an alternative if you have a lot of content layed out  imageviews and text views?

Comment: Generally speaking, start with a table view or collection view, and don't let the text views scroll independently of their parent view.  But I'd recommend checking out the [UX Help Center](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help), finding out what they're all about, and asking about your specific situation there.

Comment: @dancingbush use html and css layout your content in UIWebView. Or use TextKit&CoreText layout your content in one UITextView

Comment: @nhgrif can u explain 'don't let text views scroll independently of their parent view' do u mean disable scrolling in the tv?

Comment: No, I don't mean disable scrolling in the parent view.  The parent view already scrolls... so the child doesn't need to scroll--it just needs to take up a large portion of the parent's content view.

Comment: Ok thanks all will have to look at a redesign